# Git Pull Request: "Diff suppressed. Click to show." New lines are not new

Tags: git, github

Everybody!

After I pushed files via git and wants to make a pull request it shows:

`Diff suppressed. Click to show.` *like in the screen*

[image]

**The problem is that marked strings in Pull Request are new, but git shows that its like already exists (but it must be fully green).** Like you see file is not too long, what is the problem?

*And it seems that it depends only on new added files*

Comment: still have this issue